# Programmatically add multiple filters on one column. SatelliteForms

Tags: pocketpc, palm-os, satelliteforms

Is there a way to add more than one filter on a column programmatically?

```
Tables("TYPE").AddFilter("Code", "<>", "OP") --  Works until then next line.
Tables("TYPE").AddFilter("Code", "<>", "MP") --  The first filter is removed.
```

.... I'm not cool enough to add a SatelliteForms tag.

Here is a link to the [SatelliteForms](http://www.satelliteforms.net/).

Comment: Can you add more information, maybe a link to SatelliteForms? Is an an ASP.NET technology, or does it run under Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me put out the disclaimer that I have no experience with SatelliteForms. However, I did comb through the **[SF_MobileAppGuide](http://www.satelliteforms.net/support/SF_MobileApp_Guide.pdf)** and based on the how the **AddFilter**, **RemoveFilter** and **RemoveAllFilters** methods are called, it appears that you can only have **one filter per column**.

This explains why when you add the second line, it merely replaces your filter instead of adding it.

Comment: I have found that AppGuide to be incomplete / inaccurate more then a few times. Here is the other fun part you can add a button to a from then add multiple filters on one column. You can then execute the button's action in code. But when you have 4! possible combinations things get messy fast.